# Cannot edit example questions?

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, area-51, example-questions

I find today that I can't edit example questions on area51.  I have enough rep according to the faq, but all I see are "link" and "flag".

I can edit proposals themselves, though.

Something hinky is going on here...

I can't edit my own example questions either.  This cannot possibly be by design - editing for spelling/grammar at a minim must be allowed, if only for the sanity of picky readers!

This bug report has been upgraded to *very* hinky.

Comment: I checked many proposals, and it seems to be that same across all of them, regardless of whether I'm following it or not.  The question I want to edit in particular is http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets-why-does-my-htc-tattoo-phone-sometimes-loose-its-internet-con/5894#5894 - `loose != lose`

Comment: Possibly related is that I can't edit my own questions; there's no edit link. I figured at the time maybe it was intentional, but it seems unlikely

Comment: I fixed the spelling error. I am not entirely certain if the lack of editing is in the works or omitted by design.

Comment: Retag request: `[very-hinky]` --> `[oh-noes]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A change made last night made it so only moderators could edit questions.  It's fixed now.